# $GOPATH error while installing json2csv

Tags: bash, go

I'm running Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64. 
I want to install json2csv.

I try:

```
sudo  go get github.com/jehiah/json2csv
```

and get:

```
package github.com/jehiah/json2csv: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

go is installed:

```
GOARCH="amd64" 
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64" 
CC="gcc" 
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++" 
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

I set:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/bin/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/projects/go
```

but I still get the same error.

Any idea?

Comment: Never sudo go get. Never. Also: never set GOROOT (unless you know what you are doing).

Comment: Not only should you not set GOROOT, but that isn't a valid value for GOROOT to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is  that you lost some of your ENV when you use `sudo`.
you could use `-E` to preserve it.

you can check it out here:
https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo

**But** you should **not** use sudo to go get.

By the way, you could save you env in `.bash_profile`, so it can load automatically.

---

In this case, you should set `GOROOT` and  `GOPATH` with

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/projects/go
```

Mind that the `GOROOT` is the folder of go, no the binary of go.

then, go get without sudo.

```
go get github.com/jehiah/json2csv
```

Comment: environment variables like PATH, GOPATH, etc should always be in a profile file, not in an rc file.

Comment: @JimB Thanks, it would be a good habit doing that, updated my answer.

Comment: so what would be the solution in this case?

Comment: @xxxvinxxx I updated my answer again, actually, go get without sudo should be ok.

Comment: As covered in the comments above, don't set GOROOT (and /usr/bin/go is definitely not the value of GOROOT)